# Где лучше хранить статичные строковые ресурсы в android?

Tags: android

Допустим у меня есть некий `options.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="host">api.site.com</string>
    <string name="port">9001</string>
    <string name="protocol">http</string>
</resources>
```

И достаю значение так: `requestManager.request(getString(R.string.host), ...`

Это хороший способ, или есть более лучшая практика?

Answer (score 2):

Конкретно такие константы я бы предложил вынес в productFlavors в build.gradle файле.

```
productFlavors {
   staging {
      buildConfigField "String", "host", "\"staging.api.site.com\""
   }
   production {
      buildConfigField "String", "host", "\"prod.api.site.com\""
   }
}
```

А потом в коде использовал бы

```
BuildConfig.host
```

Answer (score 0):

В `strings.xml` обычно  хронят  данные, которые в последующем используются для переводов, а также для вывода их на экран или лог.

А стринги которые для внутренних процессов, следует записывать в отдельный `YourConfig.java`

либо в `build.gradle`

Comment: представь отдаете вы переводчикам 'Strings.xml' на перевод, как думаете им удобно работать с файлом в котором намешано всякое?

Comment: я видел часто в приложениях системные строки просто хранят в отдельном файле чтоб не путать с тем что нужно переводить.

Comment: лично мое субъективное мнение, в ресурсах не место системным стрингам, максимум idшки какие нибудь.

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать кучу разных файлов

```
res/values/filename.xml
res/values/filename2.xml
res/values/strings.xml
res/values/strings2.xml
res/values/strings_for_translate.xml
```

[Документация](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String) говорит о том, что название файла не имеет значения.

Comment: Это само-собой, но не в этом суть, возможно лучше класс с константами написать... или еще что-то... я это подразумевал в вопросе)